# What is the difference between failOnError and failOnViolation in checkstyle plugin?

Tags: checkstyle

In our project we use **checkstyle** as static analyzer (as maven plugin, I mean *maven-checkstyle-plugin*). I am new to this tool, and there is one thing I want to find out - what is the difference between **failOnError** and **failOnViolation**?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [plugin documentation is pretty clear](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html), but the minimum expectation is going to be:

- Do you want a log of the errors **before** failing the build? Then use `failOnViolation`

Or

- Do you want to fail the build **immediately**, without waiting for errors to be logged? Then use `failsOnError`

Of course, if you set `logViolationsToConsole` to `false` (or on the CLI as `-Dcheckstyle.console=false`), then both act almost identically and can cause some confusion.